# possible collisions in hashing

Tags: algorithm

If `h` is any hashing function and is used to hash `n` keys in to a table of size `m`, where `n<=m`, the expected number of collisions involving a particular key `x` is:

```
(A) Less than 1
(B) Less than n
(C) Less than m
(D) Less than n/2
```

What I figured out is, it should be less than `n` but I'm not sure.

Comment: How did you figure that? And please, when posting your homework, at least say this is homework.

Comment: Is is really worth to ask on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You best read up on the Birthday paradox.

Here are some links:

[Birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

[understanding-the-birthday-paradox](http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-the-birthday-paradox/)

And a quote from the second link:

> Here are a few lessons from the birthday paradox:
>
> - sqrt(n) is roughly the number you need to have a 50% chance of a match with n items. sqrt(365) is about 20. This comes into play in
>     cryptography for the birthday attack.
> - Even though there are 2^128 (1e38) GUIDs, we only have 2^64 (1e19) to use up before a 50% chance of collision. And 50% is really, really
>     high.
> - You only need 13 people picking letters of the alphabet to have 95% chance of a match. Try it above (people = 13, items = 26).
> - Exponential growth rapidly decreases the chance of picking unique items (aka it increases the chanes of a match). Remember: exponents
>     are non-intuitive and humans are selfish!